# Jetpack Navigation With Bottom Navigation Bar Nested Graph Transitions Animation issues

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigationview, android-bottomnav

In my current project, I have set up a bottom navigation bar with the jetpack navigation library, and each bottom destination holds it's own nested graph.

[image: bottom navigation]

Each nested graph looks like this for example, Music Home Page -> Music PlayList -> Music Details.

When navigating between bottom destinations, as long as you move destinations with the first fragment of each bottom navigation item, the proper default animation plays.

e.g; Places Home -> Music Home = Default animation played.

However, if you go from Music Home Page to Music PlayList with a slide left transition, and then you navigate to Places Home  -> Places Details, when you select the music destination, it brings you to Music Playlist Fragment, as it should, however the animation played is the slide left transition and not the default one that plays between the upper level destinations.

I would like to have the default animation played whenever selecting between bottom navigation destinations, including when the nested graph is not at it's upper destination state, however I am unsure how to fix this issue.